# Handling rotation changes and user leaving activity

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation, screen-rotation

So I’ve got this Activity with a doSomething() method. This method must be called when the user leaves the Activity and resumes after a while. This code works fine. The problem is: When the user rotates the phone (orientation change), the method is also called. I don’t want the method to be called on Orientation Change. Here’s my Activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  private static boolean callMethod=true;
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(callMethod)
           doSomething();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        callMethod=true;
    }

private void doSomething()
{
    Log.i(“doSomething()”,”Did something.”);
}
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(callMethod)
          doSomething();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From API 13 you can use `configChanges` in manifest.

Add the following to the manifest. This prevents recreation of the activity on screen rotation:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity_name"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

One note is after this, you should handle screen orientation change yourself. you should override the following function in your activity for that:

```
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_landscape);
    }
    else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);         
    }
}
```

Comment: Only adding that line to the manifest didn't work. But it helped. I also added if(!isChangingConfigurations())
            callMethod = true;
and now it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see in your comment that you added the isChangingConfigurations() flag, which should do the trick, but you should persist that state rather than making it a static variable. Otherwise, if your process is killed when your app goes to the background you'll lose that state.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String KEY_CALL_METHOD = "key_call_method";

    private boolean callMethod = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onCreate(savedState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedState != null) {
            callMethod = savedState.getBoolean(KEY_CALL_METHOD);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); 
        if (callMethod) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (!isChangingConfigurations()) {
            callMethod = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_CALL_METHOD, callMethod);
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        Log.i("doSomething()", "Did something.");
    }
}
```